# How to add a Node pointer to a Vector pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, nodes

I am trying to create a maze that consists of Nodes objects. Each Node object has a member variable

```
Node *attachedNodes[4]
```

that essentially contains all of the attached Nodes that will later tell the program the options it has when it is doing a breadth first search. Every time I think that I understand pointers, another issue like this comes up, and I feel lost all over again. Especially since it was working fine (as far as I knew) until I changed something that I thought was unrelated. Anyways, here is where the issues are:

My Node object looks like this

```
class Node {
public:
    ...
    void attachNewNode(Node *newNode, int index);
    ...
private:
    ...
    Node *attachedNodes[4];
    ...
};
```

My function to attach the Nodes looks like this:

```
void Node::attachNewNode(Node *newNode, int index) {
    *attachedNodes[index] = *newNode;
}
```

And then lastly, the part of the other function that is calling the attachNewNode function looks like this:

```
int mazeIndex = 0;
while (inStream.peek() != EOF) {
    int count = 0;
    Node n;
    Node m;
    ...
        if (System::isNode(name2)) {
            m = System::findNode(name2);
        }
        else {
            m = Node(name2);
            maze[mazeIndex] = m;
            mazeIndex++;
        }
        Node *temp;
        *temp = m;
        n.attachNewNode(temp, count); //The error usually happens here, but I added the rest of the code because through debugging it is only consistently in this whole area.
        count++;
    }
    n.setNumberUsed(count);
}
```

Sorry that this got a little lengthy, but I've been searching all over this portion that I have provided trying to figure out what is wrong, but it would be nice to have someone that knows a little more about pointers give their input on the matter. The Node class was given to me, but everything else I made, so basically any of that could be changed. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Most of this code doesn't seem relevant to the question. Step through your code in a debugger and narrow it down to the part you're confused about.

Comment: @MrEricSir I have been using the debugger, but like I said, I've tried to change a lot of things around due to my lack of knowledge on pointers. My error is coming up at the n.attachedNewNode(temp, count) call most times, but I suspect it is caused by an error that I made in my previous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class contains a property:

```
 Node *attachedNodes[4];
```

The above says that attachedNodes is an array that contains 4 pointers to Nodes. In your attachNewNode function, you do:

```
*attachedNodes[index] = *newNode;
```

This means that you are trying to assign *value* of newNode (as * dereferences the pointer) to the *value* of the element under attachedNodes[index]. What you probably want is:

```
attachedNodes[index] = newNode;
```

This means that you just want to store the address (as pointer is just an address to some place in memory) in the array of addresses.

There is also another error here:

```
Node *temp;
*temp = m;
n.attachNewNode(temp, count);
```

Again, you are interested in storing the address of node *m*. In order to do that, you need to get the said address:

```
Node *temp;
temp = &m;
n.attachNewNode(temp, count);
```

These are the most obvious problems with the above code, but there might be more.

Comment: This worked...for now. Thank you. I had been trying different combinations of these things but I guess I just didn't try the right one. That's where I really haven't fully wrapped my brain around pointers and how they should be used.

Comment: Please read more about pointers. I think it really helps if you think about them as addresses in memory and you can either change the address (by assigning different thing to a pointer) or change the value of the memory under that address (by dereferencing a pointer with * and then assigning), but blindly trying different combinations is not the proper way to go.

Comment: I understand the logic of pointers. I really just struggle with the syntax and what *, &, and just plain variables do in each scenario.